# USB Flash Drive Mounting and Unmounting Issues in linux

Tags: linux, mount, usb-flash-drive, unmount

[image]

I'm seeking assistance as I delve into learning the Linux file system, and I've encountered a specific issue regarding the mounting and unmounting of a pendrive. Upon initially inserting the pendrive and executing the 'lsblk' command in the terminal, it is identified as 'sdb' with its partition 'sdb1' (as seen in the first image). However, after unmounting using the 'unmount sdb' command, upon reconnecting the pendrive, it no longer appears as 'sdb' with its partition in subsequent instances (as shown in the second image).

I have diligently checked both the "/dev/" and "/mnt/" directories, but unfortunately, I couldn't find any relevant information. Notably, the pendrive is not corrupted, as it functions seamlessly on my Windows system. I'm perplexed by this behavior and am reaching out for any insights or solutions you may have. Your assistance is greatly appreciated

[image]

command 'lsblk' result, when i inserted USB flash drive first time, and second

'lsblk' result, when i unmount USB flash drive and again insert it

Comment: What messages do you have in the kernel log (`dmesg` or `journalctl -k`) after connecting the device again?

Comment: @u1686_grawity when i connecting my pendrive and using 'dmesg' command it will show this -> "usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device"

Comment: Let there be 10 seconds or so between unmounting and reinsertion. Does that make any difference?

Comment: @Hannu I experimented with various settings and discovered something strange. While working on VMware version 17.5.0, I encountered this problem. However, when I replicated the same steps on another VMware with version 17.0.2, I did not face the issue. I followed identical steps in both versions, and it seems that the problem might be specific to the new version (17.5.0) of VMware (maybe).

Comment: Try updating what corresponds to 'Guest Addition' (Virtualbox, can't remember the name for VMWare), maybe there is glitch in those utilities. Normally a dialog appears as you insert USB media, you have to respond appropriately - do you get this dialog?

Comment: The folder where automatic things get mounted is `/meda/$USER/`.

Comment: @Hannu Yes, I encounter a dialog box every time I insert a pen drive. when I mount and dismount graphically; it functions correctly during those instances. However, when I perform these actions through the terminal and use 'umount' for unmounting, I face this particular problem.

Comment: @Hannu I thought this only happened in my VMware with the Parrot OS. However, when I inserted the pen drive into Kali, I encountered the same problem, even though I didn't mount or unmount anything on it. I may need to try uninstalling and reinstalling VMware once and see if the issue persists. I think that might be worth a try.